# how to send email template on custom button click in crm

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-4, dynamics-crm-online

I done adding an custom button in grid view of customized entity , from here how to set action for that button to send email for selection of associated records.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a workflow to send email, and then use javascript to trigger that workflow when you click the custom button.

Comment: thanks @ nixjojo , but is it possible to get "To field (email from selected records)" in workflow for sending email.

Comment: @Vishnu Yes, you can get selected records guid via javascript, and then you retrieve the email address of that record. You need to create email pragmatically in your workflow activity.